# How to find a given value in a string Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I get a string on request, using guzzle

```
 $import = new ServerInviteClient();
$response = $import->client->request('GET', 'cB2EDPJ9wr');
$items = $response->getBody()->getContents();
dd($items);
```

`$id = 1234567`

There are more than 1000+ words in this line and I need to find the given value `$id`

I tried to search through `whereLike`, but it didn't work out, due to the fact that this is not a string in the database, but a query
How do I find the values in this string?

**-------Edit**

Part of `dd($item)`, I need to find `$id = xqc` in this line

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html class="tw-root--hover"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>Twitch</title><meta property="og:title" content="xQc - Twitch"/><meta pr
operty="og:video:secure_url" content="https://player.twitch.tv/?channel=xqc&amp;player=facebook&amp;autoplay=true&amp;parent=meta.tag"/><meta property="
al:ios:url" content="twitch.tv/xqc"/><meta name="twitter:app:name:iphone" content="Twitch"/><meta name="twitter:app:id:iphone" content="id460177396"/><m
eta name="twitter:app:url:iphone" content="twitch.tv/xqc"/><meta property="og:type" content="video.other"/><meta property="og:video:height" content="378
"/><meta content="https://www.twitch.tv/xqc" property="og:url"/><meta name="title" content="xQc - Twitch"/><meta name="twitter:image" content="https://s
tatic-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/xqc-profile_image-9298dca608632101-300x300.jpeg"/><meta property="al:android:package" content="tv.twitch.android.a
pp"/><link rel="alternate" media="only screen and(max-width: 640px)" href="https://m.twitch.tv/xqc"/><meta name="twitter:description" content="{[][][][]
[][\][\]&#39; \&#39; &#39;\\&#39;][]\]\]\]\]\][]\[]\[\][[]\[]\;[]&#39;; .&#39;;. \;&#39;/\;]/\][\]\[][\[\][][\P][\P][\P][\P][\P][\P[]P[]\][\[][\]&#39;[\
&#39;][&#39;["/><meta property="og:image" content="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/xqc-profile_image-9298dca608632101-300x300.jpeg"/><met
a property="og:video" content="https://player.twitch.tv/?channel=xqc&amp;player=facebook&amp;autoplay=true&amp;parent=meta.tag"/><meta property="og:vide
o:type" content="text/html"/><meta property="al:ios:app_name" content="Twitch"/><meta name="twitter:app:id:googleplay" content="tv.twitch.android.app"/>
<meta name="twitter:app:id:ipad" content="id460177396"/><meta name="robots" content="index"/><meta name="twitter:title" content="xQc - Twitch"/><meta pr
operty="fb:app_id" content="161273083968709"/><meta property="al:android:app_name" content="Twitch"/><meta name="twitter:app:name:googleplay" content="T
witch"/><meta property="og:site_name" content="Twitch"/><meta property="og:description" content="{[][][][][][\][\]&#39; \&#39; &#39;\\&#39;][]\]\]\]\]\]
[]\[]\[\][[]\[]\;[]&#39;; .&#39;;. \;&#39;/\;]/\][\]\[][\[\][][\P][\P][\P][\P][\P][\P[]P[]\][\[][\]&#39;[\&#39;][&#39;["/><meta name="twitter:card" cont
ent="summary"/><meta name="twitter:site" content="@twitch"/><meta property="og:video:width" content="620"/><meta content="id460177396" property="al:ios:
app_store_id"/><meta name="twitter:app:name:ipad" content="Twitch"/><meta name="twitter:app:url:ipad" content="twitch.tv/xqc"/><meta name="description"
content="{[][][][][][\][\]&#39; \&#39; &#39;\\&#39;][]\]\]\]\]\][]\[]\[\][[]\[]\;[]&#39;; .&#39;;. \;&#39;/\;]/\][\]\[][\[\][][\P][\P][\P][\P][\P][\P[]P
[]\][\[][\]&#39;[\&#39;][&#39;["/><link rel="canonical" href="https://www.twitch.tv/xqc"/>...
```

Comment: Hello, can you show a part of $items where there is your ID ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the native php function [`strpos`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php). This function returns the index of a substring in a string, or `-1` if not found. You will need to validate that the returns value is not `-1`:

```php
$id = 1234567

$import = new ServerInviteClient();
$response = $import->client->request('GET', 'cB2EDPJ9wr');
$items = $response->getBody()->getContents();

$found = strpos($items, $id) !== -1;
```

In php 8.0+, you could use the easier [`str_contains`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-contains.php).

**However**, this is not the best approach. The `id` could be a found in another property of your items, and the results would be innacurate. A better approach is to decode the body of your response, and validate each items to see if it's id match.

You have not specified if the body is in JSON format, XML format or any other format, so we can't give you an exact answer, unfortunatly

Comment: Since you've added the content of your response, you might want to use an XML parser to fetch the correct element.

Comment: Thank you, it helped me $found = str_contains($items, $id);